# Kostka coefficients for cylindric skew Schur functions using Kostant's partition function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

There is a classical formula for computing Kostka coefficients,
[using a signed sum over permutations](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/kostkaFoulkes.htm#kostkaFromKostant):

$$
K_{\lambda,\mu} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} 
(-1)^{inv(\sigma)} \mathfrak{P}\left( \sigma(\lambda + \rho) - (\mu+\rho) \right)
$$
Recall that these are the coefficients obtained when expanding Schur functions in the monomial basis: $s_\lambda = \sum_\mu K_{\lambda,\mu}  m_\mu$.

Now, we can expand the [cylindric Schur functions](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/cylindricSchur.htm) in terms of monomials:
$$s_{\lambda/d/\mu} = \sum_\nu K_{\lambda/d/\mu,\nu}  m_\nu.$$

Is there an analog of Kostants formula for Kostka numbers, which also holds for cylindrical Schur functions (or just skew Schur functions)?

Comment: I just realized, for skew schur functions, there is such a formula, since it follows from Stembridges formula for LR coefficients